# Edit CSS using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following (simplified) HTML:

```
<div id="topMenu">

            <div class="menu_wrapper">

                <div class="logo">

                </div>

                <div class="responsive_menu" id="resp_Menu" onClick="fnResponsiveMenu()">
                </div>

                <div class="nav_wrapper">
                    <div class="navigation" id="navMenu">
                        <a href="Home.aspx">Contact Us</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="navigation" id="navMenu">
                        <a href="Home.aspx">Information</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="navigation" id="navMenu">
                        <a href="Home.aspx">Venue Details</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="navigation" id="navMenu">
                        <a href="Home.aspx">Registration & Payment</a>
                    </div>      

                    <div class="navigation" id="navMenu">
                        <a href="Home.aspx">Agenda</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="navigation" id="navMenu">
                        <a href="Home.aspx">Home</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

        </div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.navigation {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#3171B7;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
    margin:0;   
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:16px;
    height:40%;
    padding-top:10px;   
}

#navMenu{
    display:none;
}
```

and the following JavaScript:

```
function fnResponsiveMenu()
{
    var oNavMenu = document.getElementById('navMenu');
    var oDisplay = oNavMenu.style.display;

    if(oDisplay=="none")
    {
        oDisplay.style.display = "";
    }
}
```

The problem is that the div with `id="navMenu"` is not being set to visible when I click.

From looking at the DOM explorer, I can see the element is set to display:none, but when calling the JavaScript function, the display is coming back as "".

I have searched the internet, but as far as I can see I am implementing everything correctly.

Is this something to do with the CSS? Do I have an obvious error that I cant see, or is there something missing in the functionality?

Comment: Id should not same for the element.

Comment: `oDisplay.style.display = ""` should be `oNavMenu.style.display = ""` I guess ?

Comment: @Hacketo: There *is* that. :-) But the comparison will also fail.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of issues there.

1. You're using the same `id` on more than one element. That's invalid. Identifiers are ***identifiers***, they must be unique. If you want to classify elements together in a group, use a class.
2. You're looking at the `display` property of the `Element#style` object, but that won't have the value applied by a stylesheet. It will only have values *directly* applied to the element.
3. `oDisplay.style.display = "";` should be `oNavMenu.style.display = "";` (the element's `.style`, not `.style` on the string) — but that won't work to override the CSS.

You can get the active styles for the element via `getComputedStyle` (standard) or `.currentStyle` (IE-only)

```
var element = /*...get the element...*/;
var currentStyle = element.currentStyle || getComputedStyle(element);
if (currentStyle.display === "none") {
    // ...
}
```

Live example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var element = document.querySelector(".hidden");
  var currentStyle = element.currentStyle || getComputedStyle(element);
  if (currentStyle.display === "none") {
      element.style.display = "block";
  }
}, 500);
```

```html
<div class="hidden">Has class hidden</div>
```

But the better answer might well be to remove the class instead:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var classRex = /\bhidden\b/;
  var element = document.querySelector(".hidden");
  if (classRex.test(element.className)) {
      element.className = element.className.replace(classRex, '');
  }
}, 500);
```

```html
<div class="hidden">Has/had class hidden</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that almost worked, but it only made 1 of the elements visible and the rest stay hidden, am I missing something?

Comment: @Alex: The example above just picks one element. To change them all, you'll want `querySelectorAll` (which returns a list) and a loop over the list.

Answer (score 0):

Id must be different for all element like:

```
<div class="nav_wrapper">
                    <div class="navigation" id="navMenu">
                        <a href="Home.aspx">Contact Us</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="navigation" id="navMenu1">
                        <a href="Home.aspx">Information</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="navigation" id="navMenu2">
                        <a href="Home.aspx">Venue Details</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="navigation" id="navMenu3">
                        <a href="Home.aspx">Registration & Payment</a>
                    </div>      

                    <div class="navigation" id="navMenu4">
                        <a href="Home.aspx">Agenda</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="navigation" id="navMenu5">
                        <a href="Home.aspx">Home</a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: While true, it doesn't relate to the issue with the element not becoming visible. **One** of them should have.

Answer (score 0):

As @ketan wrote, The ID of an element should be unique. HTML works with it being non-unique, but it's a bad practice.

You should consider using [jquery](http://jquery.com/) in your javascript, then you can select all the elements with css style selectors, like `$(".navigation")`, and change them all together.

For example, you can easily change your code to the one line:
`$(".navigation").hide()` which will hide all elements with the `navigation` class.

Answer (score 0):

All in one code solves your problem.

It displays all the hidden tags in the navList

Try running this code ( @Alex ):

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .navigation {
            width:100%;
            background-color:#3171B7;
            border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
            margin:0;   
            text-transform:uppercase;
            font-size:16px;
            height:40%;
            padding-top:10px;   
            }

        #navList{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fnResponsiveMenu()
        {
            var oNavMenu = document.getElementById("navList");
            if(oNavMenu.style.display=="")
            {
                oNavMenu.style.display = "inline";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu_wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
            <img></img>
        </div>

        <div class="responsive_menu" id="resp_Menu" onClick="fnResponsiveMenu()">
            Click to show
        </div>

        <div class="nav_wrapper" id="navList">
            <div class="navigation" id="navMenu">
                <a href="Home.aspx">Contact Us</a>
            </div>

            <div class="navigation" id="navMenu">
                <a href="Home.aspx">Information</a>
            </div>

            <div class="navigation" id="navMenu">
                <a href="Home.aspx">Venue Details</a>
            </div>

            <div class="navigation" id="navMenu">
                <a href="Home.aspx">Registration & Payment</a>
            </div>      

            <div class="navigation" id="navMenu">
                <a href="Home.aspx">Agenda</a>
            </div>

            <div class="navigation" id="navMenu">
                <a href="Home.aspx">Home</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've also faced the same issue once. The easiest possible solution is use jQuery selector [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp).

In jquery you can easily access any field using following code [detail link](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#id').attr('style')
```

and set that attribute using following code

```
$('#id').attr('style','')
```